# SQL Server 2008 R2: How to get Free spaces Between times

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two columns in a table that represent `start` and `end` for an employee work time (It Stores HH:MM:SS). I have another table working as Stack where I store the Busy time. Let's say I stored this as a result for an employee where `start` is 8:00:00 and `end` is 17:00:00

```
startColumn         endColumn
08:15:00.0000000    08:45:00.0000000
11:00:00.0000000    12:00:00.0000000
12:00:00.0000000    13:00:00.0000000
```

I want to get the following as a result considering the above data is in the table:

```
8:00 A.M
8:45 A.M
10:00 A.M
1:00 P.M
2:00 P.M
3:00 P.M
4:00 P.M
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about if startColumn  = 08:30:00 and endColumn=09:30:00?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: OKay ima change the question.

Comment: I just changed the 08:00:00.0000000    09:00:00.0000000 to

Comment: 08:15:00.0000000    08:45:00.0000000 trying to give more details

Comment: Yes, the change is small, but the logic you need to get the requested result is really something new. Nevertheless I'll edit my answer to offer you a solution which deals with quarters of an hour, but it will not give you the requested result as you've put it there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else looking for the same here is what i did

```
DECLARE @Contador INT
DECLARE @start TIME
DECLARE @end TIME
DECLARE @request INT
DECLARE @Max INT
DECLARE @Libres TABLE(Id INT,startTime TIME, endTime TIME)
DECLARE @Result TABLE(Id INT,Horario VARCHAR(8))
SET @Contador = 1

INSERT INTO @Libres VALUES (1,'08:00:00.0000000','10:00:00.0000000');
INSERT INTO @Libres VALUES (2,'11:00:00.0000000','14:00:00.0000000');
INSERT INTO @Libres VALUES (3,'14:00:00.0000000','15:00:00.0000000');

SET @Max = (SELECT MAX(id) Id FROM @Libres)

WHILE(@Contador <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Libres))
        BEGIN

            SET @START = (SELECT startTime FROM @Libres Where Id = @Contador)
            SET @END = (SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, -60 ,endTime) FROM @Libres Where Id = @Contador)
            SET @REQUEST = 1

            ;WITH Dates AS (
            SELECT @request AS Id,@Start AS reqDate
            UNION all
            SELECT Id+1,DATEADD(MINUTE,60,reqDate) FROM Dates
            WHERE reqDate < @end
            )
            INSERT INTO @Result(Id,Horario)
            SELECT Id,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),reqDate,100) "Horarios" FROM Dates
            SET @Contador = @Contador + 1

            IF(@Max < @Contador)
                BREAK;
            ELSE
                CONTINUE;
        END

SELECT * FROM @Result
```

Comment: I'm glad, that you found a solution, although I have to admit, that unneeded loops (`WHILE ...`) were not mine...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Here is a solution with quarters of an hour, coming back with all quarters *without* working activities...

```
DECLARE @empl TABLE(ID INT, EmplName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @empl VALUES
(1,'Mr. X');

DECLARE @emplStandard TABLE(emplID INT, StartHour TIME, EndHour TIME);
INSERT INTO @emplStandard VALUES
(1,{t'08:00:00'},{t'17:00:00'});

DECLARE @Work TABLE(emplID INT,WorkDay DATE,StartHour TIME,EndHour TIME);
INSERT INTO @Work VALUES
 (1,{d'2016-02-05'},{t'08:15:00'},{t'08:45:00'})
,(1,{d'2016-02-05'},{t'11:00:00'},{t'12:00:00'})
,(1,{d'2016-02-05'},{t'12:00:00'},{t'13:00:00'});

WITH TallyTimes(TheHour) AS
(
          SELECT {t'08:00:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'08:15:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'08:30:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'08:45:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'09:00:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'09:15:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'09:30:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'09:45:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'10:00:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'10:15:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'10:30:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'10:45:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'11:00:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'11:15:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'11:30:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'11:45:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'12:00:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'12:15:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'12:30:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'12:45:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'13:00:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'13:15:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'13:30:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'13:45:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'14:00:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'14:15:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'15:30:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'16:45:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'15:00:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'15:15:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'15:30:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'15:45:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'16:00:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'16:15:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'16:30:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'16:45:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'17:00:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'17:15:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'17:30:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'17:45:00'}
)
SELECT e.EmplName
      ,CAST(CAST(tt.TheHour AS TIME) AS VARCHAR(8)) AS TheHour
FROM TallyTimes AS tt
CROSS JOIN @empl AS e
INNER JOIN @emplStandard AS es ON es.emplID=e.ID
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM @Work AS w 
                 WHERE w.emplID=e.ID 
                   AND CAST(tt.TheHour AS TIME)>=w.StartHour AND  CAST(tt.TheHour AS TIME)<=w.EndHour
                 )
```

### Following the first attempt (before the question was changed)

If I understand you correctly you are dealing with full hours only:

This will pick out the hours your employee was working:

A short explanation: After filling your test data in declared table variables I start with a CTE creating a list of all hours from 06:00 to 20:00. The final `SELECT` checks whether exists an entry within the table "Work" where the current hour is within the intervall or not. It's on you to decide, if the `EndHour` is included or not. Your own sample data are inconsistent in this point of view.

You might shift the `CASE WHEN`-logic into a `WHERE` if you really want the non-working hours only...

And be aware, that you will need further logic to distinguish between different employees, WorkDays and maybe differing time standards for each WorkDay (Friday other than Monday...)

```
DECLARE @empl TABLE(ID INT, EmplName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @empl VALUES
(1,'Mr. X');

DECLARE @emplStandard TABLE(emplID INT, StartHour TIME, EndHour TIME);
INSERT INTO @emplStandard VALUES
(1,{t'08:00:00'},{t'17:00:00'});

DECLARE @Work TABLE(emplID INT,WorkDay DATE,StartHour TIME,EndHour TIME);
INSERT INTO @Work VALUES
 (1,{d'2016-02-05'},{t'08:00:00'},{t'09:00:00'})
,(1,{d'2016-02-05'},{t'11:00:00'},{t'12:00:00'})
,(1,{d'2016-02-05'},{t'12:00:00'},{t'13:00:00'});



WITH TallyTimes(TheHour) AS
(
          SELECT {t'06:00:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'07:00:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'08:00:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'09:00:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'10:00:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'11:00:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'12:00:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'13:00:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'14:00:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'15:00:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'16:00:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'17:00:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'18:00:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'19:00:00'}
    UNION SELECT {t'20:00:00'}
)
SELECT e.EmplName
      ,tt.TheHour
      ,CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                        FROM @Work AS w 
                        WHERE w.emplID=e.ID 
                          AND CAST(tt.TheHour AS TIME)>=w.StartHour AND  CAST(tt.TheHour AS TIME)<=w.EndHour
                        ) THEN 'X' ELSE '' END
FROM TallyTimes AS tt
CROSS JOIN @empl AS e
INNER JOIN @emplStandard AS es ON es.emplID=e.ID
```

The result:

```
Empl    TheHour   WasWorking
Mr. X   06:00:00    
Mr. X   07:00:00    
Mr. X   08:00:00    X
Mr. X   09:00:00    X
Mr. X   10:00:00    
Mr. X   11:00:00    X
Mr. X   12:00:00    X
Mr. X   13:00:00    X
Mr. X   14:00:00    
Mr. X   15:00:00    
Mr. X   16:00:00    
Mr. X   17:00:00    
Mr. X   18:00:00    
Mr. X   19:00:00    
Mr. X   20:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you Shnugo. Your answer is correct considering i use full hours only. But i have another table with the time a service is done. And unfortunately i dont use full hours :(

Comment: @user3668102, as "TT" commented, your question is *little light on details*... I suppose you'll be able to get the idea and break this down to any intervall you need. Easiest was to set any wanted number of intervalls into the UNION SELECT creating the tally list.

Comment: Thank you! I Appreciate your effort helping others.

Comment: Good answer Shnuggy, just wanted to point out the fact that it is better to use UNION ALL if you know all values are distinct. UNION will look for duplicates and filter those out.

Comment: More elegant still would be to use a [Table Value Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: @TT. *Shnuggy* ??? :-) Are you going to be my stalker ;-) And of course you're right, `UNION ALL` was better, even though some 40 rows won't make significant differences. `VALUES` is better, but best would be a physically stored numbers table (eventually extended with side columns for often needed value rows).

Comment: @Shnugo =D I'm a bit of a precisian hehe.

Comment: @TT. Employer: Where are your weak points? TT: Oh, I'm bit of a precisian :-) But this is actually the main benefit of SO: When you write an answer you see other answers and you get comments - and you can **learn** I appreciate this site!

Comment: @TT, look, as I told you: I've learned! :-)) http://stackoverflow.com/a/35387546/5089204 My answer there uses `VALUES` and my comment to "Parfait" is quite similiar to the one you gave here.