# How to output 7 records for each row, 1 for each day of week?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Trying to save myself a lot of data entry here. I have the output below currently:

```
CONTID  DESCR
001     Area 1
001     Area 2
001     Area 3
```

What I'd like to do is output 7 records for each "DESCR" (Area), 1 for each day of the week (0 - 6 accordingly).

Example output would be:

```
CONTID  DESCR         DAYOFWEEK
001     Area 1        0
001     Area 1        1
001     Area 1        2
001     Area 1        3
001     Area 1        4
001     Area 1        5
001     Area 1        6
001     Area 2        0
001     Area 2        1
001     Area 2        2
001     Area 2        3
001     Area 2        4
001     Area 2        5
001     Area 2        6
001     Area 3        etc...
```

I'd like to do this with straight SQL if possible. This is for a one-time "copy/paste" job to populate a new table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might do this with a CROSS JOIN

(Thx to @TT. for pointing out, that my answercan be shortened)

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(CONTID INT,  DESCR VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (001,'Area 1')
,(001,'Area 2')
,(001,'Area 3');

SELECT *
FROM @tbl AS tbl
CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)) AS AllDays(DayInx)
```

Comment: Oh snap! that is brilliant! I knew there had to be a way to "hard code" a set of values like that. Didn't know about the VALUES() thing. Very cool! Worked perfect!

Comment: Will do - waiting for SO to let me :) - keeps yelling at me telling me to wait another 8 minutes.

Comment: Now for one more conscise: `... CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)) AS AllDays(DayInx)`.

Comment: @TT Oh sh... he's done it again! Yes, true... I had this before within a CTE but thought it's better to read as sub-select. But - your solution is cleaner. If you don't mind I'll edit my answer...

Comment: @SourceMatters, According to TT.'s comment I shortened my answer a little, might be interesting for you...

Comment: @Shnugo I'm here to share my knowledge just like you. HTH!

Answer (score 1):

Also, consider this other solution that too uses a cross join but implicitly with derived tables for any future readers needing a generalized SQL solution in their specific RDMS:

```
SELECT CONTID,  DESCR, DAYOFWEEK
FROM 
  (SELECT CONTID,  DESCR FROM dataTable) AS T1,
  (SELECT 0 As DAYOFWEEK
    UNION  SELECT 1
    UNION  SELECT 2
    UNION  SELECT 3
    UNION  SELECT 4
    UNION  SELECT 5
    UNION  SELECT 6) As WeekDays
```

Comment: Yes, right, I'll vote it up, but (to be a little picky...): better use `UNION ALL` if you know, that your values are unique...